# Kubectl create service type Loadbalancer (on GCP but add flag Global?)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, kubectl

I've create loadbalancer for my microservices, with this template:, all is good and works but wanted to somehow add the `global` flag (when you create lb through gcp console you have option to add it) to meet expectations of the app functionality, does anyone know what other flag might I need to add ?

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-app-jmprlb
  annotations:
    cloud.google.com/load-balancer-type: "Internal"
  labels:
    app: my-app
    env: dev
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: my-app
    env: dev
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 8080
    protocol: TCP
  loadBalancerIP: 10.10.10.10
  externalTrafficPolicy: Local
```

---

EDIT:
I found some nice annotations from google docs, seem to do the trick,https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/internal-load-balance-ingress

```
# web-service.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: hostname
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    cloud.google.com/neg: '{"ingress": true}'
spec:
  ports:
  - name: host1
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 9376
  selector:
    app: hostname
  type: NodePort
```

and

```
# internal-ingress.yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ilb-demo-ingress
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "gce-internal"
spec:
  backend:
    serviceName: hostname
    servicePort: 80
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to make it a global `LoadBalancer` which accessible from the outside your cluster with public IP you can use:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-app-jmprlb
  labels:
    app: my-app
    env: dev
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: my-app
    env: dev
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 8080
    protocol: TCP
```

Note that the annotation of `cloud.google.com/load-balancer-type: "Internal"` means that your service is only accessible withing subnets that were peer with the subnet where your cluster resided.